# Persist state between WM_COMMAND and WM_LBUTTONDOWN branch

Tags: c++, winapi

I have some question about `WM_COMMAND`.

Is it possible if I change variable `x` in the case branch for `WM_COMMAND` to get this new value in the case branch for `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`?
I always get `0` in the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` branch and `1` in the `WM_COMMAND` branch.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    int x = 0;
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            x = 1;
            cout << x;
            break;

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            cout << x;
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;

        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x` is a local variable that you initialize to 0 every time `WindowProcedure` is called.

Declare `x` outside of `WindowProcedure`, or make it `static`.